# SOAPUI JDBC MS SQL query is not working (TestSuite)

Tags: sql-server, web-services, soapui, testcase

I'm using SOAPUI to test a webservice I developped. I'm actually trying to configure a TestSuite with a JDBC call to a MS SQL database.
I succeeded in adding the jdbc jar files for MSSQL. The connection string is working.

The only problem I have is that it's not running any SQL query.
Whatever I may write in the query (even mistakes) is returning my this error:

```
Tue Sep 13 10:07:18 CEST 2016:ERROR:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter 'Name' was not found in the SQL Query.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter 'Name' was not found in the SQL Query.
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.support.NamedParameterStatement.getIndexes(NamedParameterStatement.java:139)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.support.NamedParameterStatement.setString(NamedParameterStatement.java:170)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.JdbcSubmit.prepare(JdbcSubmit.java:238)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.JdbcSubmit.runQuery(JdbcSubmit.java:173)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.JdbcSubmit.run(JdbcSubmit.java:147)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have passed **Name** as parameter in SQL Query, but your query **dosen't accept that parameter**, please remove passed Name parameter where you call Query

Comment: You're right ! I figured it out a few minutes ago ! I configured something in the first table (being the parameters panel) while I wasn't using it... Thanks !